# Adding if statements for checkboxGroupInput in Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm having issues adding a checkboxes in a shiny app. I want to be able to check  to add either a linear regression line, loess, or none at all. This is using the diamond data. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated:

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
fluidRow(
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    numericInput("size","Size",value=1,min=0,max=1,step=0.1),
    sliderInput("opaqueness","Opaqueness",0,min=0,max=1),
    checkboxInput("color","Color",value=T),
    checkboxGroupInput("lines","Lines",choices=c("lm","loess"))
    #add inputs

    ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("diamondgraph")
  )
)
)
))
```

**server.R**

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
data<-diamonds
data<-filter(data,color=="E"|color=="I"|color=="J")


shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$diamondgraph<-renderPlot({
g<-ggplot(data=data,aes(x=carat,y=price))
if (input$color){
  gcol<-g+geom_point(aes(color=color),alpha=input$opaqueness,size=input$size)+scale_x_log10()+
    ggtitle("Scatterplot of Carat vs Price")

}else{
  gcol<-g+geom_point(alpha=input$opaqueness, size=input$size)+
    geom_smooth()+
    scale_x_log10()+
    ggtitle("Scatterplot of Carat vs Price")
}
if (input$lines =="lm"){
  gcol<-g+geom_point(aes(color=color),alpha=input$opaqueness,size=input$size)+geom_smooth(aes(color=color, method=lm))+scale_x_log10()+
    ggtitle("Scatterplot of Carat vs Price")
}
if 
(input$lines == "loess"){
  gcol<-g+geom_point(aes(color=color),alpha=input$opaqueness,size=input$size)+geom_smooth(aes(color=color)) + scale_x_log10()+
    ggtitle("Scatterplot of Carat vs Price")
} else 
  gcol<-g+geom_point(aes(color=color),alpha=input$opaqueness,size=input$size) + scale_x_log10()+
    ggtitle("Scatterplot of Carat vs Price")
gcol
   })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easy to pinpoint the exact problem because you have a lot of code duplication and your formatting is difficult to parse. If you are using RStudio `Ctrl + I` and `Ctrl + Shift + A` will re-indent your lines and reformat your code, respectively. Here are a few problems I noticed:

1. The `input$color` setting was not being used because the other logic that checks for the `input$lines` value was just overriding it with `aes(color=color)` anyways. When you factor out a lot of duplicated code this is much easier to see.
2. `checkboxGroupInput("lines","Lines",choices=c("lm","loess"))` should be a `radioButton`. It doesn't make sense for both of these things to be true at the same time.
3. Use reasonable defaults, e.g. set `input$opaqueness` to have an initial value greater than zero.

The following runs fine for me:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

data <- diamonds
data <- filter(data, color == "E" | color == "I" | color == "J")
set.seed(123)
data <- data[sample(seq_len(nrow(data)), 3000),]

shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(fluidRow(
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                numericInput(
                    "size", "Size", 
                    value = 1, 
                    min = 0,
                    max = 1,
                    step = 0.1
                ),

                sliderInput(
                    "opaqueness", "Opaqueness",
                    min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.5
                ),

                checkboxInput(
                    "color", "Color",
                    value = TRUE
                ),

                radioButtons(
                    "lines", "Lines",
                    choices = c("lm", "loess", "none"),
                    selected = "none"
                )
            ),

            mainPanel(plotOutput("diamondgraph"))
        )
    )),

    server = function(input, output) {

        output$diamondgraph <- renderPlot({
            g <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = carat, y = price))

            if (input$color) {
                g <- g + geom_point(
                    aes(color = color),
                    alpha = input$opaqueness, 
                    size = input$size)

                if (input$lines != "none") {
                    g <- g + geom_smooth(
                        aes(color = color),
                        method = input$lines)
                }

            } else {
                g <- g + geom_point(alpha = input$opaqueness,
                                    size = input$size)

                if (input$lines != "none") {
                    g <- g + geom_smooth(method = input$lines)
                }
            }

            g + scale_x_log10() +
                ggtitle("Scatterplot of Carat vs Price")

        })
    }
)
```